# Open DropDown Menu When User Clicks The SearchBar

Tags: javascript, php, html, drop-down-menu, dropdown

So Intended result should be, when the user clicks on the SearchBar, A dropdown list with Users open and gets filtered according to what the user enters. Below is the code for the DropDown List.

```
<div id="myDropdown" class="form-group">

      <label class="control-label">Employee Name</label>

      <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()" onclick="openDropDown()">

      <select id="uni_name_drpdwn" class="form-control custom-select" name="emid" data-placeholder="Choose a Category" tabindex="1" value="" required>

        <?php asort($allemployees); foreach($allemployees as $value): ?>
           <option id="openDrpDwn" value="<?php echo $value->em_id ?>"><?php echo $value->first_name.' '.$value->last_name ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </select>
</div>
```

Below is the code to filter the list when the user clicks the SearchBar(PS. This works fine)

```
function filterFunction() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;

//Line Below Should Open DropDown List
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");

input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
a = div.getElementsByTagName("option");
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
txtValue = a[i].textContent || a[i].innerText;
if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
  a[i].style.display = "";
} else {
  a[i].style.display = "none";
  }
 }
}
```

How can I get the DropDown List Open When Clicked On The SearchBar? I've tried a few codes and failed. example below

```
document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
```

Comment: Sadly you cannot open a dropdown/select via JavaScript. You are going to have to find a new solution.

Comment: You can use a jQuery plugin like niceSelect. It will do the job easy.